# case statement is returning a 0 instead of empty string

Tags: sql, t-sql, case

I have the following case statement;

```
case when (
    CASE 
    WHEN datediff(year,view_3.[PERSON BIRTH DATE], @ReportPeriodStartDate)  >= 19 AND view_3.[NI NUMBER] IS NOT NULL 
        THEN '' ELSE view_3.[NI NUMBER]  END ) = 0 then '' else view_3.[NI NUMBER] END AS [NI NUMBER],
```

I would like it to return

```
Birthddate  NI Number   

14/04/2012  9000
06/05/2020  2000
01/01/2001
22/12/1998
```

But the output I am getting is;

```
Birthddate  NI Number   

14/04/2012  9000
06/05/2020  2000
01/01/2001  0
22/12/1998  0
```

I dont want the zeros, I would like the empty string.

Comment: `CASE` **expression**. And an empty string isn't a value `int` value (`''` as an `int` is actually implicitly cast back to `0`). Though you *could* convert everything to a `varchar`, that not a good idea (`9` is not greater than `10`, but `'9'` *is* greater than `'10'`). Sounds like a job for your display layer, not the data engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to return a string, so you need to cast the `else`:

```
else cast(view_3.[NI NUMBER] as varchar(255))
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This answered my question